# cscope: -c or -T mismatch between command line and old symbol database

Tags: c, tags, cscope

I'm trying to create tags for `*.c`, `*.x` and `*.h` files.

These are the following commands which I executed.

```
find <absolute_path_of_code> -name *.c -o -name *.x -o -name *.h > cscope.files
cscope -bkqc cscope.files
```

Till here everything is ok.

But after this when I execute the command,

```
cscope -Rb
```

I get the following message at console.

```
cscope: -c or -T option mismatch between command line and old symbol database
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you generate a database using the `-c` or `-T` options (you use `-c` in your original command) you are required to pass those options to every subsequent invocation of cscope. Just add `-c` to your second command (making it `cscope -Rbc`) and it should work.

Comment: No @Evan, this time there is another message.
`cscope: -q option mismatch between command line and old symbol database`.

Comment: @Adarsh - If you figured out the solution by yourself, why not make it an answer to benefit the future generations that arrive here as a result of searching the Internets for the cscope error message (like myself)!

Comment: Ya I get it @FooF. I'll move my comment to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`cscope -Rb` generates only `cscope.out` file but `cscope -bkqc -I cscope.files` generates `cscope.in.out`, `cscope.po.out` and `cscope.out`. So there is no need to execute `cscope -Rb`.